# Задание шрифтов "по-умолчанию"

Tags: windows, qt5, x11

При создании кросс-платформенных приложений не всегда (а скорее чаще) не известно наличие конкретных шрифтов на целевой системе. Подскажите, пожалуйста, возможно ли каким-то образом получить имена шрифтов, используемых по умолчанию для моноширинной и пропорциональной гарнитуры? Если "да", то как?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Подсказали неплохой вариант - [`QFont QFontDatabase::systemFont(SystemFont type)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfontdatabase.html#systemFont)